# MySQL: Obtain Column Head Names From CSV

Tags: mysql, csv, import

I have a MySQL database into which I import several large datasets from CSVs for analysis.  Has anyone developed a SQL script that will do these two things?

1. Read the first line of the CSV and extract all of the column names, and
2. Go through the entire  CSV file and determine the longest field for each column

My thinking is that if I could get this info within MySQL, then I could use that info to create the table with the correct column names and lengths for each column.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a tool called [sqlizer.io](http://sqlizer.io) which does exactly what you're after. Upload your CSV file and leave the "Has Header Row" option ticked. It will analyse the contents of the CSV file and generate a CREATE TABLE statement with the column names from the top row and the correct data types to be able to import your data.

It will also create a set of INSERT statements to import your data.

(Disclaimer: I help run SQLizer)

Comment: This is the best solution I have seen, and it works just as needed! It even converts spaces in the column names to underscores. Many thanks for sharing.

Comment: By not disclosing your affiliation, this is considered SPAM.
https://d4nt.com/how-sqlizer-io-became-the-internets-1-database-import-tool/

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres ok, I've added a disclaimer. It's a freemium tool that I run part time and I was only trying to be helpful.

Comment: Understandable. I've done a quick search and most of the posts including sqlizer.io were from you and / or other team members and none disclose the affiliation.

Answer (score 0):

Ideas? Sure.

[Learn Perl](http://qntm.org/files/perl/perl.html), install [DBD::mysql](http://search.cpan.org/~capttofu/DBD-mysql-4.025/lib/DBD/mysql.pm) to talk to the server and [TEXT::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-1.32/lib/Text/CSV.pm) to read the file and you should have something working by this time tomorrow.

For bonus points, you can also implement the ability to read [XLSX](http://search.cpan.org/~dmow/Spreadsheet-XLSX-0.13-withoutworldwriteables/lib/Spreadsheet/XLSX.pm) files from Excel.

Comment: I do not have the ability to install anything else on my work computer, so I am restricted to using native SQL and nothing else, at least for the moment. I will look into this down the road, for sure! Many thanks!